# Как получить данные из нескольких баз?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Имеется N баз данных с одинаковой схемой и табличка, в которой хранятся имена баз данных. По особому критерию я выбираю все нужные мне имена баз. Затем мне необходимо применить запрос к каждой базе из полученного на предыдущем шаге списка, а все результаты объединить в одну таблицу. Подскажите, каким образом это сделать?
Вручную это бы выглядело как–то так

```
SELECT Cnt, DBName
FROM
(
    SELECT 
      COUNT(*), 'MyDB1'
    FROM 
      MyDB1.dbo.Files
    UNION ALL
    (
        SELECT 
          COUNT(*), 'MyDB2'
        FROM 
          MyDB2.dbo.Files
    ) UNION ALL
    (
        SELECT 
          COUNT(*), 'MyDB3'
        FROM 
          MyDB3.dbo.Files
    ) UNION ALL
) X;
```

Как получить тоже самое, если имена базы данных выбираются из мета-таблицы?

Comment: Соединяетесь в каждую базу и отдельным запросом получаете данные. Получится данные в нескольких переменных потом обединяете списки

Comment: Не понятно, о какой все таки СУБД идет речь? В тегах и mysql и MS SQL.

Comment: А так динамический sql поскольку имя таблицы и базы данных лежат в гдето. Формируете строку запроса из ваших мета данных и запускаете скиптор

Comment: @AzizUmarov Поясните, пожалуйста, на примере.

Answer (score 2):

Что-то такое

```
DECLARE MyCursor CURSOR FOR -- курсор для получения данных
SELECT 
    DB_NAME(t.db_id) DBname
    , SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id) Schemaname
    , t.name AS TableName
FROM  ... ваши источники и условия

OPEN MyCursor

DECLARE @DB VARCHAR(100),  @Schema VARCHAR(100), @Table VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)=''


FETCH FROM MyCursor INTO @DB, @Schema, @Table -- формируем запрос
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0    
BEGIN   
    SET @SQL = CASE WHEN @SQL <> '' THEN ' UNION ALL ' ELSE '' END + 'SELECT COUNT(*), ''' + @SCHEMA + ''' FROM ' + @Db + '.' + @SCHEMA + '.' + @TABLE   
END

CLOSE MyCursor
DEALLOCATE MyCursor

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Updated.

```
CASE WHEN @SQL <> '' THEN ' UNION ALL ' ELSE '' END
```

Вы в цикле курсора формируете запрос. На случай когда `@SQL` пустой  `UNION ALL` не нужен.

Comment: Спасибо! Подскажите, что делать, когда у нас запрос к базе ~100 строк с вьюшками и работой с множеством таблиц?

Comment: Подскажите, зачем нужно `CASE WHEN @SQL <> '' THEN ' UNION ALL ' ELSE '' END `?

Comment: По поводу  ~100 строк с вьюшками нужно смотреть что там и почем. Данный динамический sql будет работать на ограниченном запросе. Если он неограниченный то делите на подзапросы и объединяйте